# Array of class Objects

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to save objects in array then call them like so:

```
array.push( Object );
var o:Object = new array[0]();
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.push( Object );
var o:Object = new ( array[0] as Class )();
```